# Concatenating JSON output for multiple dataframes from pd.to_json()

Tags: python, json, pandas

I want to combine several dataframes and write to a singular JSON file.

```
import json 
import pandas as pd 

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [10, 11, 12]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C': [1, 2, 3], 'D': [10, 11, 12]})

with open('df1_df2.json', 'w') as js:
    for df in [df1, df2]:
        df.set_index(df.columns[0], inplace=True)
        parsed = json.loads(df.to_json())
        print(json.dumps(parsed, indent=4))


>>>
{
    "B": {
        "1": 10,
        "2": 11,
        "3": 12
    }
}
{
    "D": {
        "1": 10,
        "2": 11,
        "3": 12
    }
}
```

As the above would not make a valid json file, I am not sure the best way to write these json objects to a file. The name of the main keys (df1, df2) can be anything. The format I want is:

```
{
   "df1":{
      "B":{
         "1":10,
         "2":11,
         "3":12
      }
   },
   "df2":{
      "D":{
         "1":10,
         "2":11,
         "3":12
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert dataframe to dictionary than combine dictionaries to one object, then dump to json

```
import json 
import pandas as pd 

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [10, 11, 12]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C': [1, 2, 3], 'D': [10, 11, 12]})

combined = {"df1": df1.to_dict(), "df2": df2.to_dict()}
print(json.dumps(combined, indent=4))
```

This generates:

```
{
    "df1": {
        "A": {
            "0": 1,
            "1": 2,
            "2": 3
        },
        "B": {
            "0": 10,
            "1": 11,
            "2": 12
        }
    },
    "df2": {
        "C": {
            "0": 1,
            "1": 2,
            "2": 3
        },
        "D": {
            "0": 10,
            "1": 11,
            "2": 12
        }
    }
}
```